# I have to use Visual Studio 2005. What are good alternatives to using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net

I have recently started a new job and am being forced to use VS 2005 and .NET 2. This has been quite painful for a number of reasons, but the one big change from VS 2005 to its successors was the introduction of LINQ and extension methods.

A common pattern that I used to follow when using enumerations was the following:

```
foreach(var myObject in myObjects.Where(x => x.Property == someValue)
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

What I am having difficulty with is coming up with a succinct way of expressing the same statement in C# 2.  The best I have come up with is the following:

```
foreach(MyObject myObject in myObjects)
{
    if(myObject.Property == someValue)
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Is there a more effective or efficient way of writing this code?

How would you write C# 2 code so that it can most easily be transformed into C# 5 code (we will be upgrading to VS2012/.NET 4.5 after the next release)?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your new team if they are not willing to change to VS 2008 (with .NET FW 2 as target platform). The .NET 3.5 compiler works greatly with .NET Fw 2.0, and with Linqbridge you can code as if you had almost full Linq available.

Comment: I would love to move to either VS2010/2012, but I get absolutely zero say in the matter.  The boss won't buy it until the next release is out.  I have tried explaining how the later compilers will increase productivity greatly, but to no avail.  I should add that I'm the sole developer on this project and report straight to the boss.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Express edition is free, and (unlike previous express versions of VS) allows commercial use.

Comment: @Peregrine: previous express editions have been free for commercial use, too.

Comment: Moving from VS2008 or earlier to VS2012 can be a quite a pain in the *** (and expensive!), esp if you have C++ projects in your solution.

Comment: @Stephen - you never know what wierd, difficult-to-track-down errors you're going to get with the new version. As someone who's just migrated from VS2002 to 2010, we've had to spend much longer than I anticipated on such issues. With a release round the corner, you stick with what works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you have a few interesting bits to overcome:

- Lambda syntax wasn't introduced until VS 2008, so you'd have to implement using anonymous delegates.
- You can't even simulate extension methods for .NET 2 with VS 2005. VS 2008 only.
- `Func<>` and its relatives weren't introduced until .NET 3.5
- The `Func<>` delegates are covariant on their input and contravariant on their output. Not going to have that until .NET 4, so your use may be limited.

That being said, if you grab [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/), you should be able to remove the extension method syntax and use it.

**EDIT**

So, for grins and giggles, I just translated LINQBridge into .NET 2.0 / VS 2005. Was easy, but not terribly pleasant :) Your example `foreach` above would wind up looking like this after the re-do:

```
foreach(MyObject myObject in Enumerable.Where(myObjects, delegate(MyObject x) { return x.Property == someValue; }))
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

This makes me think that your non-LINQ `foreach` is much easier to read for the environment you're working in.

Comment: +1 for _non-LINQ foreach is much easier to read_

Comment: "Lambda syntax wasn't introduced until VS 2008" etc. immediately made me think of "there won't be a gas station around until sometime next century!" (sorry, I couldn't resist :) )

Comment: There is *always* win in tapping in a Back to the Future III quote!

Answer (score 4):

Before LINQ has been introduced we used PowerCollections (https://powercollections.codeplex.com/). To give you some examples:

```
Algorithms.Convert(enumerable, converter) <=> enumerable.Select(converter)
Algorithms.Exists(enumerable, predicate) <=> enumerable.Any(predicate)
Algorithms.FindFirstWhere(enumerable, predicate) <=> enumerable.FirstOrDefault(predicate)
```

and so on.
Unfortunately, you will have to use this clunky "delegate (...) { ... }" syntax instead of lambda syntax, but technically it's the same thing.

Good luck!